# Injecting service into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I have a service that will do some stuff and directive where I want to call it.

But when I execute the directive, it will throw:

> rror: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider:
>   ExportSvgProvider <- ExportSvg <- solutionDiagramDirective

My service declaration is:

```
define(['angular', './module', 'underscore'], function (angular, module, _) {

    module.service('ExportSvg', [function() {
```

and Im injecting it into controller like this:

```
define(['angular', 'jquery', 'underscore', '../module', 'd3', 'dagre'], function(angular, $, _, module, d3, dagreD3) {

    return module.directive('solutionDiagram', ['Entity', '$interpolate', '$resource', 'ExportSvg', function(Entity, $interpolate, $resource, ExportSvg) {
```

Any idea what can cause that problem?

Comment: are you using requirejs ?

Comment: Yes, Im. Do you have any idea?

Comment: add ExportSvg as dependency to resolve ['angular', 'jquery', 'underscore', '../module', 'd3', 'dagre', 'ExportSvg' ]

Comment: You can get help from http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/09/30/requirejs-angularjs-dependency-injection/